# Java servlet application running behind squid proxy on windows

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, jvm

I'm behind a squid HTTP proxy requiring authentication and want to make API requests to an external server. However when I do so, I get the following error :

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

I've tried setting the proxy configuration by going to Control Panel > Java > Network Settings, but to no avail.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the proxy-settings in java.

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
I would prefer something that would require me to set proxy settings in the tomcat server directly instead of setting them up in the code.
This way, I'll never have to worry about the proxy settings in my future projects.

Comment: You could try adding them to the tomcat startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Copy from http://www.it.iitb.ac.in/~roshan/articles/javahttpproxy.html:

Tomcat Settings: catalina.properties

Append these properties to the catalina.properties file in Tomcat: ${CATALINA_OME}/conf/catalina.properties file:

http.proxyHost=yourProxyURL
http.proxyPort=yourProxyPort
http.proxyUser=yourUserName
http.proxyPassword=yourPassword
Tomcat Settings: catalina.bat

Add all the parameters defined above in the ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.bat (for Windows) or ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.bat (for *nix):
JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxyURL ..." 
(Each option is seperated by spaces.)